# laravel 5 authentication not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits

I have the following problem. I'm developing a website using php and laravel 5.0.33. I have a development machine and a web server.

Now, I'm intercepting the register process by overriding the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` `postRegister` method, but with no luck because the interception is not performed on the server, on my local environment all works as expected.

I have also putted a `die();` on the postRegister method of my AuthController, the one that overrides the defined on the mentioned trait and that line is never reached.

---

#### Original Trait method on `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` :

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

---

#### My overrided method inside AuthController on `\Project\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` :

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

//Override of the register process
public function postRegister(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    die ('aqui');
}
```

So, what is preventing the code from entering my overrode method?
In both, my local dev machine and the server, the php versions are the same.

**Edit:** Bad news the same behavior happens if I try to log in a user on the website, the login is not working as the register. The request never gets to the controller. This has cost me a whole day....:(. On the login I also overrode a method.

Comment: Can't think of a reason why this would happen except for cached routes. Run `php artisan route:list` on local and server machine and paste here.

Comment: @BharatGeleda the routing is fine, the two listings show that the auth routes redirect to the correct controller and action. The thing is like if the authentication is down.

Comment: Can you route to other methods on your AuthController? I suspect nothing can get to your AuthController

Comment: @Jessedc Yes indeed, I can show the login page, the recover password page, the register page....The thing is I think with the POST method. But the routes are untouched they are the same that came out of the box with laravel.

Comment: Can you get to any _custom_ methods of your own?

Comment: @Jessedc Yes, all methods but the overrode postLogin and postRegister. The most curious thing is that on my dev environment works fine. And there is nothing on the error log, the methods are never called. The server uses Cloudfare for caching, and now is in Dev Mode to prevent caching.

Comment: I suspect `artisan route:list` will show the route for that method pointing directly to the base AuthController or something similar. Make sure you clean up any route caches you have lying around.

Comment: @Jessedc and how I clean the route cache? Sorry, I'm new on laravel.

Comment: Take a look at the artisan command. `php artisan` Everything is listed.

Comment: More precisely `php artisan list`. Did you find the problem though?

Comment: @BharatGeleda Not yet, it's dark magic...

Answer (score 1):

So, the error was due to a misconfiguration on the virtual host done by the hosting providers in which all requests urls get a trailing slash, but if a POST request is done and the trailing slash is added then the consequent redirection transforms the POST request into a GET one. After two days of explaining this to the hosting providers, I got the access to modify the virtual host configuration and I added a rule to avoid redirecting POST requests.

This was the redirection before the fix:

```
   # Enforce trailing slash policy
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /es/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

And the redirection after the fix:

```
   # Enforce trailing slash policy
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /es/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks to all for your interest and responses.